# Is it possible to encode MP4 video with VP9 codec?

Tags: mp4, mkv, vp9

Does MP4 support VP9 codec or is it exclusive to WebM?

Answer (score 3):

ffmpeg v4.0.2 or higher can encode/transcode VP9 in mp4.

Commandline (when transcoding):
ffmpeg -i INPUT.MKV -c:v libvpx-vp9 OUTPUT.MP4

Commandline (when remuxing (Super fast)):
ffmpeg -i INPUT.MKV -c:v copy OUTPUT.MP4

Comment: Your second command isn't transcoding, it's called remuxing, the process of moving encoded streams from one container to another. Transcoding involves going from one codec to another and requires decoding the source stream and encoding it into the destination stream.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg, a command-line app, can write VP9 streams in MP4s.

Get a static daily/snapshot binary from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Basic command is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -c:v vp9 out.mov
```

Comment: Getting error: Unknown encoder 'vp9'

Comment: Works here. You got the 20170317 static build, right? Use full form: `-c:v libvpx-vp9`